# Getting runtime error: reference binding to misaligned address 0xbebebebebebebebe for type 'int'

Tags: c++

I'm working on this leetcode problem https://leetcode.com/problems/meeting-rooms-ii/
and am getting this error:

Line 1034: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to misaligned address 0xbebebebebebebebe for type 'int', which requires 4 byte alignment (stl_vector.h)
0xbebebebebebebebe: note: pointer points here

SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:9

My approach is to create a vector of pairs that stores the rooms and whether they are full or not.

```
public:
   static bool sortcol(const vector<int>& v1, const vector<int>& v2){
       return v1[1] < v2[1];
    }
    int minMeetingRooms(vector<vector<int>>& intervals) {
        sort(intervals.begin(), intervals.end(), sortcol);
        vector<pair<int, bool>> roomfull;
        for(int i = 0; i < intervals.size(); i++){
            if(intervals[i][1] > intervals[i+1][0]){
                for(int k=0; k < roomfull.size(); k++ ){
                    if(roomfull[k].second==false){
                       roomfull[k].second = true; 
                    }
                    else{
                        roomfull.push_back(make_pair(roomfull.size(), true));
                    }
                }
            }
            
    }
        return roomfull.size();
    }
};
```

Comment: `intervals[i+1]` is out of bounds on the last iteration

Comment: Something as regular as bebebebebebe has to be the program trying to tell you something, but I don't recognize that code.

Comment: `if(intervals[i][1] > intervals[i+1][0]){` -- Change that to: `if(intervals[i][1] > intervals.at(i+1)[0]){`.  Now, what error do you get?  I bet it isn't a wall of hexadecimal addresses -- instead it should be a `std::out_of_range` error.

Comment: Aside: it seems that `roomfull` could just be an `int` counter - the `bool` part is never `false`, so all you do is add one whenever the `if` is true.

Answer (score 0):

```
     for(int i = 0; i < intervals.size(); i++){
        if(intervals[i][1] > intervals[i+1][0]){
```

When you get to the end of the loop (`i == intervals.size() - 1`), the statement `intervals[i+1]` indexes past your vector bounds (which is undefined behavior). Adjust your loop to end 1 iteration earlier.